# Solr wildcard search with Boolean operator

Tags: solr

I am trying to run some wildcard searching with Boolean operators. When I run the following query, I get the appropriate results :-

```
q=field1:*val1 val2* AND field2:val3
```

The above displays all those records where val1 and val2 occur in field1 in any combination and field2 contains the value val3.

However, if I run the following query :-

```
q=field1:*val1 val2* AND field2:val3 AND -field3:(*val1 val2* *:*)
```

field1 searching starts behaving strangely. As far as I understood the debugQuery result, the above query is first searching for those records where either val1 or val2 (or both) appear in field1, filters it by field2 and then filters those records where field3 does not contain the **combination** of val1 and val2. So, this query can display those records where val2 (and not val1) is present in field1.

I tried proximity search also in field1. No effect. Later on though, I read that proximity search does not work with wildcards.

The fields above are defined as  :-

```
<field name="field1" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
<field name="field2" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" />


<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="select">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>

    </fieldType>
```

field3 is a string and it is not giving any problems.  Is it possible to modify the above query so that  the searching for field1 only results in those records where both val1 and val2 are present (any combination is acceptable)?

Update: It worked when I did the following :-

```
q=field1:*val1 AND field1:val2* AND field2:val3 AND -field3:(*val1 val2* *:*)
```

However, is there any way to accomplish the same without chopping up my phrase into individual words?

Answer (score 1):

You say that:

```
field1:*val1 val2*
```

Searches for anything were val1 and val2 both occur.  Unless you have implemented this syntax yourself, I can't find any documentation of such syntax in either Lucene or Solr.  It should search for:

```
field1:*val1 OR defaultfield:val2*
```

If you want to search for the presence of both in field1 (not sure what you are intending to accomplish for the wildcards, but leaving where they are for the time being):

```
field1:(+*val1 +val2*)
```

Also, `-field3:(*val1 val2* *:*)` means you will omit all results that contain either `*val1`, `val2*` or `*:*`, and that last I read as anything containing a colon, and I'm not sure whether it will work correctly.

```
field1:(*val1 AND val2*) AND field2:val3 AND -field3:(*val1 val2* *:*)
```

Or (because I must provide my preferred query syntax as an alternative, at least):

```
+field1:(+*val1 +val2*) +field2:val3 -field3:(*val1 val2* *:*)
```